# Linux nice command

Tags: linux, command, nice

When I try to assign the nice value to a program for example:

```
nice -n -7 waffles
```

It will not allow me to run the program in the background as well with the bg command.

Is there a way I can pipe the output to the bg command? Such as:

```
nice -n -7 waffles | bg
```

I have tried that and

```
bg | nice -n -7 waffles
```

I'm running it in a script and I have also tried examples such as:

```
nice -n 7 waffles & 
waffles & nice -n 7
```

to start the program in the background. Any help at all would be great appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following format should works fine:

```
nice -n 7 waffles &
```

e.g.

```
nice -n 5 date &
[1] 30920
Thu May  4 17:32:19 IDT 2017
```

Adding `&` at the end of the command sends it to the background